# Domain keeps going to the default apache config

Tags: apache-2.4, virtualhost

I have an apache2 setup (Ubuntu 16, Apache 2.4.18) with a number of virtual hosts defined. Each virtualhost has it's own .conf file in /etc/apache2/sites-available with a softlink to /etc/apache2/sites-enabled.

All but one of the virtualhosts work correctly. I have triple checked that the `ServerName` matches the domain (it does), but when I go to that domain, I end up at `DocumentRoot` for the default virtualhost and I have no idea why. I also deleted and re-wrote the whole `ServerName` line in case there was some hidden control character.

I have done a diff between one of the working virtualhosts and the one that doesn't work, and the only differences are the `DocumentRoot` and the `ServerName`.

I have checked that there are no other virtual hosts with the same domain (the only other one is the SSL virtual host)

Is there anything else I can look for to help figure out the issue?

EDIT: As requested, the VH file (domain name/folder obscured and comments removed for brevity)

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerName MYDOMAIN.COM
    ServerAdmin webmaster@MYDOMAIN.COM
    DocumentRoot /var/www/MYDOMAIN.COM

    ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/error.log
    CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/access.log combined
</VirtualHost>
```

EDIT 2: I removed the default VH and restarted, then the problem VH worked fine. I re-added the default VH and restarted, and the problem VH continued to work fine for about 20 seconds, then it reverted to the same problem.

Comment: If you show us the VH in question maybe we can help

Comment: Did you check the Apache error log for any clues?

Comment: I will add it in a sec, but other than `ServerName` and `DocumentRoot` it's identical to a working one, so I suspect the problem is outside of the VH file, I just have no idea what it could be!

Comment: No errors in the apache error log

Comment: Where do you specify the `<Directory> ......` block

Comment: I don't have a `<Directory> ...` block for this VH

Comment: Is it possible that it needs a `<Directory> ...` block to make it work?

Answer (score 0):

As far as I can tell, the problem was happening because the domain was listed in the /etc/hosts file and set in /etc/hostname. Removing it from there seemed to fix the problem.